# Error arise when trying to access HDFS file on AWS from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I have successfully installed hadoop and spark on AWS EC2 following [this tutorial](http://blog.insightdatalabs.com/spark-cluster-step-by-step/).
I can access HDFS from spark on AWS.

However, when I try to access HDFS file from my local machine through

```
val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://namenode_public_DNS:9000/datasets/wikipedia/wikipedia.dat")
lines.first()
```

I get

```
17/04/10 16:35:41 WARN BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/datanode_ip:50010]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

1. All AWS instances are set to allow for all traffic.
2. I have only 1 namenode and 1 datanode

Comment: The IP of datanode returned by Namenode to the Client is Private IP which cannot be accessed from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The port that you are using for hdfs, should be accessible from outside.
Try to run this command in your local machine.

```
$telnet namenode_public_DNS 9000
```

And check weather you are able to access your hdfs port.

Comment: The output is `connected to namenode_public_DNS`, `Escape character is '^]'.` But I still can't connected to the dataset.

Comment: also enable firewall for 50010 port in your all the datanode.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have configured your [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for your EC2 instance correctly. By default, the security group configuration for your EC2 instance will not allow inbound traffic. You can add new rules to your security group by applying the procedures given at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule and adding inbound traffic for port `9000` (you don't need to do anything for outbound, because Security Groups are stateful).

Comment: I have checked that all instances' are set to allow all traffic.

Comment: For testing purpose, can you install Hadoop locally, so that you can try `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://namenode_public_DNS:9000/datasets/wikipedia/wikipedia.dat`? To see whether it is at least possible to list file?